# Convert a color Image to a 3D Surf plot in Java

Tags: java, plot

I have an image that uses warmer and cooler colors to represent depth in a 2D space. I want to be able to plot it as a 3D surface plot as you are able to do in Matlab. I have been playing around with jzy3d but I'm new to java so I am having trouble doing this. Ideally, like in Matlab, the best way to go about this is to convert it into grayscale and then plot it but I don't know how to so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do it in Java? then please edit your post for clarification. Also, edit the tags.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I am cramped on time.

Answer (score 1):

You should describe in more detail what the *actual* difficulties are.

However, I was curious (and wanted to try out jzy3d anyhow). So I modified the [SurfaceDemo.java](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-tutorials/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos/surface/SurfaceDemo.java) sample to load an image and plot the value of the [Hue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) of the individual pixels.

[image]

It bascially boils down to what "warmer" and "cooler" exactly mean (no pun intended), but it should be possible to derive this from the hue value. (**NOTE**: The color in the image is only a color of the plot, and unrelated to the colors in the image. The colors from the image only determine the *height* of the plot at each point.)

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.jzy3d.analysis.AbstractAnalysis;
import org.jzy3d.analysis.AnalysisLauncher;
import org.jzy3d.chart.factories.AWTChartComponentFactory;
import org.jzy3d.colors.Color;
import org.jzy3d.colors.ColorMapper;
import org.jzy3d.colors.colormaps.ColorMapRainbow;
import org.jzy3d.maths.Range;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.Builder;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.Mapper;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.concrete.OrthonormalGrid;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Shape;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.rendering.canvas.Quality;

public class BasicJzy3D extends AbstractAnalysis
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("lena512color.png"));
        AnalysisLauncher.open(new BasicJzy3D(image));
    }

    private final BufferedImage image;

    BasicJzy3D(BufferedImage image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the RGB value in the given image at the specified location,
     * which is given in relative coordinates (between 0.0 and 1.0).
     * Invalid coordinates will be clamped to the border
     * 
     * @param image The image
     * @param x The x coordinate
     * @param y The y coordinate
     * @return The RGB value
     */
    private static int getRGB(BufferedImage image, double x, double y)
    {
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        int ix = (int)(x * w);
        int iy = (int)(y * h);
        ix = Math.max(0, Math.min(w-1, ix));
        iy = Math.max(0, Math.min(h-1, iy));
        int rgb = image.getRGB(ix, iy);
        return rgb;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the hue for the given RGB color
     * @param rgb The RGB color
     * @return The hue
     */
    private static float getHue(int rgb)
    {
        int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int g = (rgb >>  8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (rgb >>  0) & 0xFF;
        float hsb[] = new float[3];
        java.awt.Color.RGBtoHSB(r, g, b, hsb);
        float hue = hsb[0];
        return hue;
    }

    static class ImageToValueMapper extends Mapper
    {
        private final BufferedImage image;

        ImageToValueMapper(BufferedImage image)
        {
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        public double f(double x, double y)
        {
            int rgb = getRGB(image, x, y);
            float hue = getHue(rgb);
            return hue;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        Mapper mapper = new ImageToValueMapper(image);

        // Define range and precision for the function to plot
        Range range = new Range(0, 1);
        int steps = 80;

        // Create the object to represent the function over the given range.
        final Shape surface = Builder.buildOrthonormal(
            new OrthonormalGrid(range, steps, range, steps), mapper);
        surface.setColorMapper(
            new ColorMapper(new ColorMapRainbow(), 
                surface.getBounds().getZmin(), 
                surface.getBounds().getZmax(), 
                new Color(1, 1, 1, 1.0f)));
        surface.setFaceDisplayed(true);
        surface.setWireframeDisplayed(false);

        // Create a chart
        chart = AWTChartComponentFactory.chart(
            Quality.Advanced, getCanvasType());
        chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surface);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your feedback. I am actually trying to run what you did, just to see it, but it isn't working for me. I am getting this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout
 at org.jzy3d.analysis.AnalysisLauncher.open(AnalysisLauncher.java:12)
 at BasicJzy3D.main(BasicJzy3D.java:24)

Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Jzy3D uses "log4j" for logging. You can probably configure this to use another logger, using some `properties` files, but I don't know how from the tip of my head. The easiest will be to download the JAR from https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html and add it to the classpath.

Comment: Yeah I just forgot to add the dependencies. Thank you Mr.Marco.